# App Engine matching any "subdomain" to my service

Tags: google-app-engine, strapi

I have a Strapi application on Google App Engine as the Default service.

The default URL App Engine generates is https://my-project.uc.r.appspot.com

When I create any other version for my default service or deploy another service, the new URLs would be something like: https://**[identifier]**-dot-my-project.uc.r.appspot.com

My problem is that if I replace **[identifier]** with anything at all it opens my Strapi Application root page.

I don't think this has anything to do with Strapi at all, it's probably a feature of App Engine.

My question is: How do I stop this from happening? I want only proper URLs to be matched. That is, if I create a "dev" version, I should be able to access it with the following URL: https://dev-dot-my-project.uc.r.appspot.com, but I don't want any other URL to be matched, like: https://12345-dot-my-project.uc.r.appspot.com

I am using a Standard Environment with the [default app.yaml from Strapi docs](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/deployment/hosting-guides/google-app-engine.html#create-app-yaml-and-gcloudignore)

```
runtime: nodejs16

instance_class: F2

env_variables:
  HOST: '0.0.0.0'
  NODE_ENV: 'production'
  DATABASE_NAME: 'strapi'
  DATABASE_USER: 'postgres'
  DATABASE_PASSWORD: '<password>'
  INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME: '<instance_identifier>'

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: '<instance_identifier>'
```

When the app is deployed to App Engine, the app.yaml is automatically modified to add some default params.

```
runtime: nodejs16
env: standard
instance_class: F2
handlers:
  - url: .*
    script: auto
```

I thought maybe this `url: .*` was the cause of this and tried to change it to `url: /.*` [(Docs)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/reference/app-yaml?tab=node.js#handlers_element), but App Engine still add the `url: .*` again anyway at the end and it will have both handlers.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior. Per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed#soft_routing)

> If a request matches the PROJECT_ID.REGION_ID.r.appspot.com portion of the hostname, but **includes a service, version, or instance name that does not exist**, then the request is routed to the default service.

In your example, when you hit the url - https://12345-dot-my-project.uc.r.appspot.com and it turns out '12345' is not a valid version, the default service - https://my-project.uc.r.appspot.com will take over.

If you really want to block it, you'll have to write code to read the incoming url (i.e. the original url that came in), determine the version and if it's not in your list of versions, you raise an error (maybe return 404). This is basically what you'd do if you were offering a service built on GAE where each of your users had their own custom domain (version of your app) e.g. a blog hosting platform, an ecommerce site (like Shopify)